# How run application after deploying with CircleCI to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am currently trying to deploy a python Hello World application 
to AWS S3 using CircleCI. The basic flow works as follows:

Local PC -> GitHub -> CircleCI -> AWS S3

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: /tmp/myfiles
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:2.7-jessie
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
            name: Test
            command: echo "Deploying files"
      - run:
           name: Install awscli
           command: sudo pip install awscli
      - deploy:
           name: Create application
           command: aws s3 sync helloWorld.py s3://mysite.s3.amazonaws.com --delete
      #  Do I do something here to run program???
```

Once the file is successfully uploaded, I would like to execute the python script. Instead of doing a basic "Hello World" console output, I am creating a file so there is evidence that the script successfully ran.

Comment: please mention more details you want to deploy it in full ec2 server or lamda function would also work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I gave up and switched to Elastic Beanstalk. It seems that S3 is generally used for storage rather than application deployment.